# Pandas Resample Data By Hour Creates Nonexistant Data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a very long dataset of meteorological observations taken every minute from 16:23:27 April 11th, 2019 to 13:40:19 April 18th, 2019. I have read these data into a Pandas Dataframe and set the index to be a datetime object for timeseries plotting.

```
df = pd.read_csv('11_18April2019.csv', engine='python')
month_to_num = {"April":4}
df["Month_Num"] = df["Month"].apply(lambda x: month_to_num[x])
df_time = df[["Year", "Month", "Date", "Hour", "Min", "Sec"]].astype(str).agg("".join, axis=1)
df["Date_Time"] = pd.to_datetime(df_time, format="%Y%B%d%H%M%S")

# Set date column as index
temp_hourly_index = df.set_index('Date_Time')
```

I want to plot hourly averaged values for each parameter (hourly averaged temperature instead of temperature every 1 minute for example).

The easiest way to do this seemed to be the pandas "resample" function which I applied to my dataframe:

```
hourly_avg_data = temp_hourly_index.resample('H').mean()
```

However, when I print(hourly_avg_data), I get 176 rows including some hours for which there is no data (14:00 - 23:00 April 18th, 2019). There should only be 165 rows (16:00 April 11th to 13:00 April 18th). Why is this resampling giving me too many rows? Where is it getting that data? How can I get resampled hourly averaged data for only the hours I want (and for which there is data)?

Comment: That's what `.resample` does - it fills in the gaps... have you tried: `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date_Time', freq='H')).mean()` and see if that gives you what you want? As that won't fill gaps.

Comment: @JonClements I just tried that, but still got back 176 rows including data from those hours for which there is nothing.

Comment: Have you checked your input to definitely make sure you haven't actually got something there or tried adding a `.dropna()` to the end?

Comment: @JonClements, yes the input has nothing there after 13:40 April 18th. This was confirmed both by looking at the actual file (all 10k+ lines) and printing my original dataframe, which displays by default the first and last 5 lines. I also tried adding .dropna() to no avail. Still giving me 176 rows